# Combining in_memory and custom user provider

Tags: symfony, authentication, in-memory

I have a custom user provider (let's call it `MyUserProvider`) that is used to create a custom user (`MyUser` or `MyOtherUser` depending on the user, but never mind). Usually this user provider is used with SSO/CAS authentication (through the BeSimpleSSOBundle).

However in development environment, I can't use the SSO/CAS authentication and I must use an other authentication. I thought that `in_memory` authentication would be fine. But I still need to use `MyUserProvider`.

The problem is that if in my `security_dev.yml` file I only mention MyUserProvider, the user won't be authenticated (`security.INFO: Authentication request failed for user "kelux": The presented password is invalid`). Why? Because `MyUser` class doesn't know about the password of the user (it is delegated to the SSO/CAS). That's why I want to use the `in_memory`.

But I don't want to use the `in_memory` alone. If I do so, then the User that will be used is the default `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`, which is not what I want.

And I don't want to chain them since I want both of them not one or the other.

Here is the `security_dev.yml` (as in the first case I described):
    security:
        encoders:
            Alecsia\AnnotationBundle\Entity\MyUser: plaintext

```
    providers:
       entity:
            id: alecsia.MyUserProvider
    firewalls:
             secured_area:
                 pattern:    ^/
                 http_basic:
                     realm: "Secured Demo Area"
```

And the `alecsia.MyUserProvider` service is described as is (it relies on three services to know which type of user it is):

```
services:
    alecsia.Lille1UserProvider:
        class: Alecsia\AnnotationBundle\Security\User\MyUserProvider
        arguments: [@alecsia.MyService,@alecsia.MyOtherService,@alecsia.MyLastService]
```

So how could I provide a `in_memory` authentication (for the dev environment only) while using MyUserProvider?

Thanks for your help!